# Cannot plot datetime in x-axis matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the datetime in x-axis using this code

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
from datetime import datetime


figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax=plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
dates = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')).values
datenums=md.date2num(dates)
_=plt.plot(x=datenums,y= values)
```

My dataframe contains dates like this `2018-05-09 13:27:31.319283` but I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert -1 to a date.  This often happens if
>   non-datetime values are passed to an axis that expects datetime
>   objects.

Comment: Since you say you have dataframe I assume you are using pandas.  You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your string dates into datetime dtypes instead of using the datetime module `strptime` method.  This is much easier.  `pd.to_datetime' implicity understand many different date formats, so you should need to do the format.